# Load In Custom View Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

This is for a Mac App and not for iPhone.  What I want to do is take my current xib "Welcome Screen" and when it opens, load in another xib "WelcomeScreenText1" in a custom view called myTargetView.  When it runs the error message is "[NSViewController loadView] loaded the "WelcomeScreenText1" xib but no view was set." Please help!

```
#import "WelcomeMainViewController.h"
#import "WelcomeText1ViewController.h"
#import "WelcomeText2ViewController.h"


@implementation WelcomeMainViewController


NSString *const text1Title      = @"WelcomeScreenText1";



- (void)awakeFromNib
{   
            WelcomeText1ViewController* imageViewController =
            [[WelcomeText1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:text1Title bundle:nil];
            if (imageViewController != nil)
            {
                myCurrentViewController = imageViewController;  
            }

    // embed the current view to our host view
    [myTargetView addSubview: [myCurrentViewController view]];

    // make sure we automatically resize the controller's view to the current window size
    [[myCurrentViewController view] setFrame: [myTargetView bounds]];

}


- (NSViewController*)viewController
{
    return myCurrentViewController;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means that the nib didn't connect anything to the `view` outlet of the view controller.

In your nib, make sure the custom class of File's Owner is set to `WelcomeMainViewController`.  Then make sure that the `view` outlet of File's Owner is connected to the top-level view of the nib.